# IOS - How to use partial views

Tags: iphone, ios

i'm kind of confused right now. I'd like to use a partial view (= a region of the whole view) in many of my views and moreover i'd like to do it via storyboard.

These partial views usually have functions (they have to pass some kind of input to the "main" view controller).

So my question is: how can i (if possible) properly reuse those partial views without having add them to the superview in my code (i'm aware that i'll probably have to set the "main" view controller as a delegate in the code)?

I thought it could maybe possible via container views.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for the way to chose a subview class at `Interface Builder` ? If so, that is done at `Identity Inspector` `Class` textfield (`Custom Class` section). You'll also be able to set it's outlets then. If you meant something different, please explain it more clear.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help. That's partially what i'm trying to do. But furthermore i'd like to be able to design that subview class via interface builder and also create its outlets. Maybe that's done with a xib file, i guess right now.

Comment: You can have a separate xib for that views class, use `loadNibNamed` to load it at your view constructor, get the view from the loaded xib and use it as a subview. I still have a feeling of not understanding the problem completely, is there anything else missing ?

Comment: As i sayed, i'm a bit confused myself. I wan't to reuse a region of a view, completely with outlets and connected actions in many of my view controllers in storyboard. So to say i don't want to copy the region and redefine all the outlets and actions. Hope that's a bit more clear again...

Comment: Using the same view as a subview several times seems to be a good way to find all kinds of troubles. The way I see to do it right is to make  a constructor doing all the job, e.g. preparing the view and assigning controls actions so that all instances are doing the same job and look the same. Having a factory is better if you want the solution to be reusable and well-scalable (look for the "factory pattern" if needed).

Comment: Hey,I just started with Swift for IOS, Can you show me how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them in a UIContainer. and have a UIContainer class with the container's frame size etc., and then create a standard view class to load into that container. If you want to use storyboard, that has been the best solution for me.